# wlan1 interface disappeared from ifconfig

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, interface

I was trying to make a virtual interface on my wlan1 card (like set hostednetwork from windows) by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan1:0 
iface wlan1:0 inet static
address 192.168.4.1
netmask 255.255.255.0 
wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

When that failed I have tried with `ap-hotspot`:

```
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
cd /tmp && wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb && sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

That also failed. After that I have installed the default `network-manager` and I have noticed that I can see wifi networks around but can't connect to them. I have tried to reinstall wlan drivers and nothing.

I will provide some info about how it looks on my system

```
sudo airmon-ng
Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlan1       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]

sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
# PCI device 0x8086:0x4237 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:24:d6:5f:8f:94", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
```

Moreover this virtual wlan1:0 interface sits still on the system, and won't delete by `ifdown`

```
 sudo lshw -C network
     *-network               
           description: Wireless interface
           product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
           logical name: wlan1
           version: 00
           serial: 00:24:d6:5f:8f:94
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-46-lowlatency firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
           resources: irq:45 memory:90700000-90701fff
      *-network
           physical id: 2
           logical name: mon.wlan1

 sudo ifconfig 
    eth1
    lo
    mon.wlan1:0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

(note that I have removed eth1 and lo config for clarity). More info about interfaces and driver:

```
    :/sys/class/net$ ls -alh
    total 0
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 mar 14  2015 .
    drwxr-xr-x 54 root root 0 mar 14  2015 ..
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 mar 14 20:11 eth1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/eth1
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 mar 14  2015 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 mar 14 20:11 mon.wlan1:0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/mon.wlan1:0
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 mar 14 20:11 wlan1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan1

 :lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection [8086:4237]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1311]
    Physical Slot: 1
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 45
    Region 0: Memory at 90700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

How can I get rid of this wlan1:0 interface and make wlan1 to show and work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You present a lot of information in a very confusing way, but I think your problem is not severe. You said your interfaces file contained:

`auto wlan1:0

iface wlan1:0 inet static

address 192.168.4.1

netmask 255.255.255.0

wireless-mode ad-hoc`

Please change it to:

`auto wlan1

iface wlan1 inet static

address 192.168.4.1

netmask 255.255.255.0`

and reboot.

If it still doesn't work remove ap-hotspot and network-manager because you did install those manually.

Comment: Ok I have removed, and changed the file. However after calling `sudo ifup wlan1` I get an error: `Error getting interface address for 'mon.wlan1:0'; No such device
Error getting interface information.
Failed to bring up wlan1.` Seams `'mon.wlan1:0'` exist and blocks my wlan1 to start. Problem is I don't know how to get rid of it `sudo ifdown wlan1:0` does not work.

Comment: What does ifconfig show?

Comment: Hey thank you, after restart I was able to `ifup wlan1`. Now it works. I have also instaled Wicd as an alternative tool to network-manager.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to hear we've solved your problem.